# CircuitHandler Equivalent for .NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Where is `CircuitHandler` in Blazor .NET 6?

As I am upgrading packages to .NET 6, I noticed in nuget package manager that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server` package was marked obsolete and so assuming `CircuitHandler` was moved to another package and that one is no longer needed (As they have done in the past with `IAsyncEnumerable` and `Span<T>`), I removed the package. Then I realized that package has completely been removed from nuget browser altogether, and there is no word anywhere I can find on any alternative for .NET 6. MSDN even has Blazor .NET 6 articles talking as if `CircuitHandler` is easily found in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server` namespace, but no mention of what package or how to get access to that namespace! Example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-server-circuit-handler)

Comment: I think this is just part of the App SDK package

Comment: I figured it out finally, I have to use `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` instead of `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`

Comment: Nice! Yeah that is what I meant.  It is part of the App SDK Package.  So you should have access to it by referencing it.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I figured this out, as I noticed the type exists in my BlazorApp project, but not my library project. It was a matter of figuring out what the differences are, and it turns out that you need to put `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` in the project file instead of `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`. So just adding the `.Web` part fixed the issue!</strike>

Note: Now my library won't build because it says I need a static `Main` method entry point. So it seems they aren't allowing `CircuitHandler`s in class libraries anymore, they must all reside in the Web App itself. Total bummer!

The real solution is to add the following to your project file. What a runaround this was for me to figure out! And I could not find this documented anywhere!

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```